# extract and concanate the last 4 hidden states from bert model for each input

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, feature-extraction, bert-language-model

I want to extract and concanate 4 last hidden states from bert for each input sentance and save them
I use this code but i got last hidden state only

```
class MixModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,pre_trained='bert-base-uncased'):
        super().__init__()        
        self.bert =  AutoModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
        self.hidden_size = self.bert.config.hidden_size
        
      
           
    def forward(self,inputs, mask , labels):
        
        cls_hs = self.bert(input_ids=inputs,attention_mask=mask, return_dict= False,  output_hidden_states=True)        
        print(cls_hs)        
                   
        encoded_layers = cls_hs[0]
        print(len(encoded_layers))

        print(encoded_layers.size())
        #output is [1,64,768]
       
        return encoded_layers
```

batch size is 1
padding size is 64

how to extract the last four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grab the last 4 hidden states, now a tuple of 4 tensors of shape (batch_size, seq_len, hidden_size)

```
encoded_layers = cls_hs['hidden_states'][-4:]
```

and concatenate them (here over the last dimension) to a single tensor of shape (batch_size, seq_len, 4 * hidden_size)

```
concatenated = torch.cat(encoded_layers, -1)
```

Comment: too many indices for tensor of dimension 3   I got this error in cls_hs['hidden_states'][-4:] because it represent last hidden state only

Comment: That doesn't agree with the documentation at https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.15.0/en/main_classes/output#transformers.modeling_outputs.BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions. Try setting `return_dict=True`.

Comment: I try return_dict= True . It worked . Thank you very match